# How do i declare a variable of type NSLayoutConstraint in an extension in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

I have created an extension for my UIViewController and I want to declare some variables which I can use through out the extension. Below is my code

```
extension UIViewController {

var mssgTopConstraint1: NSLayoutConstraint?
var mssgTopConstraint2: NSLayoutConstraint?
var mssgIconTop1: NSLayoutConstraint?
var mssgIconTop2: NSLayoutConstraint?
var isCheviClicked: Bool = false

}
```

I have this error extension may not contain stored properties for all five variables.

Comment: You can't extend existing types with new instance variables. If you a library provides you an object (with a certain memory layout, to store is properties), but your code expected these new instance methods, where are they supposed to come from? Where would they get stored?

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear, you cannot add stored properties within an extension, you can only use computed properties.

You can subclass `UIViewController` and declare those properties within your custom class:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var mssgTopConstraint1: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var mssgTopConstraint2: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var mssgIconTop1: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var mssgIconTop2: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var isCheviClicked: Bool = false    
}
```

This is a cleaner approach, as extending `UIViewController` with those properties doesn't makes too much sense as not all controllers need those properties.

You can instantiate this new controller, or set the class name in XIB/Storyboard to be `MyViewController`. This way you can use the new controller and the newly declared properties.

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement getter and setter directly while declaring a variable into an extension you have to create a holder otherwise it will create a retain cycle here is an example.

```
extension UIViewController {
struct Holder {
    static var contraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
}

var actualVariable: NSLayoutConstraint {
    get {
        return Holder.contraint
    }
    set {
        Holder.contraint = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Happy coding

Comment: Can't implement this with NSLayoutConstraint

Comment: @chevi99 What does that even mean?

Comment: @Alexander i have edited my question may be you can get the clear picture. Thanks

Comment: He wanted to create property into the extension this example is how we can create.